# Cast TextBox control from linq query

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, collections, controls

I'm trying to get a `TextBox` control from a collection which only contains TextBoxes as follow:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> tbx = this.grd.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
```

And then I'm trying to get the `TextBox` control that has the name "tbxLink" as follow:

```
TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)tbx.Select(x => x.Name == "tbxLink");
```

But it gives me this error message at runtime:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Windows.Controls.TextBox,System.Boolean]' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'.
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:

Some more tries with some more error messages:

Using `.Where`:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Windows.Controls.TextBox]' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'.
```

Using `.Single`:

```
Sequence contains no matching element
```

Using `.First` :

```
Sequence contains no matching element
```

Using `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` makes the tbx variable `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally use Where like this:

```
 IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = tbx.Where(x=>x.Name == "tbxLink");
```

where textBoxes is `IEnumerable<TextBox>`.

But if you know there is only one text box with that name you need

```
tbx.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "tbxLink");
```

which will return null (of more precisely `default(TextBox)`) if there is no text box of that name,

or alternatively

```
tbx.Single(x => x.Name == "tbxLink");
```

which throws an exception if no text box of that name exists.

If there are multiple text boxes with the same name you may want to use

```
tbx.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "tbxLink");
```

or

```
tbx.First(x => x.Name == "tbxLink");
```

As an example running this code in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) works as expected:

```
void Main()
{
     IEnumerable<TextBox> items = new List<TextBox>{
        new TextBox{ Name = "One" },
        new TextBox{ Name = "Two" },
        new TextBox{ Name = "Three" },
        new TextBox{ Name = "Four" },
    };

    items.Single (i => i.Name == "One").Dump();
}

class TextBox
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have duplicated this using WPF, e.g.

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = grid.Children.OfType<TextBox>();

        var textBox = textBoxes.Single(tb => tb.Name == "one");

        Debug.WriteLine(textBox.Name);
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i used the 'Where' clause too but that failed me too. There are multiple textboxes but the names are identical. So would SingleOrDefault work for that too or only if there is one textbox?

Comment: @Yustme: If there are multiple textboxes with the same name, why are you expecting to be able to assign to a single `TextBox` variable?

Comment: Then do you want tbx.First(x => x.Name == "tbxLink")?

Comment: @Jon, i said 'the names are identical' which means no textbox has a name that another textbox already has.

Comment: @Yustme: No, that's not what "names are identical" means. That's what "names are *unique*" would have meant. Names being *identical* means exactly the opposite - that they've got the *same* name. If the names are really unique, then `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` should work.

Comment: @Jon, my bad, that's exactly what i meant. But in my defence, English is not my mom's language.

Comment: @Phil, i tried them all, they all generate an error msg at run time.

Comment: @Yustme: "an error message" isn't very useful - please tell us *exactly what happens*.

Comment: Are you getting the same exception or a new one?

Comment: @Phil, im using an explicit type: TextBox txtBox, your using var. And i need it to work for an explicit type not var. How would that be done?

Comment: Changed answer to use IEnumerable<TextBox>.  You don't need any explicit casts because you are using OfType<TextBox> which ensures only controls of type TextBox are returned by your query.

Comment: @Phil, i found out why it didnt work for me. I was using 'grd' which i thought had my textboxes on it, but it turns out that they where on an 'canvas'. Changing 'grd' to 'canvas' fixed the problem. I assumed that tbx had items, but doing a Count(), showed 0. Stupid me!